# Erro ao inserir dados com Mysql e laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho uma tabela chamada **"item"** no qual preciso inserir dados, porem por algum motivo não processa o **insert**. Sou novato no backend por tanto não sei se existe alguma restrição na tabela que impede de inserir o registro.

```
mysql> desc item;
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                                                                      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned                                                          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id           | int(10) unsigned                                                          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| proc_id           | int(10) unsigned                                                          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date              | datetime                                                                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| code              | varchar(100)                                                              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status            | enum('Waiting','Canceled')                                            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user              | int(10) unsigned                                                          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp                                                                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp                                                                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

O código que realiza o insert é este, $item_id seria uma **string** como **'222'** por tanto passei ela para inteiro:

```
if ($item_id != '') {

                DB::table('item')->insert([
                    'item_id' => settype($item_id, 'integer'),
                    'proc_id' => null,
                    'date' => Carbon::now(),
                    'code' => null,
                    'status' => 'Waiting',
                    'user' => null
                ]);
    }
```

Comment: Opa Mário, acontece algum erro?

Comment: @AndréLins então, não tenho log disponivel no console. Estou vendo como posso habilitar ainda.
O interessante é que isso só ocorre quando uso no schedule com cronjob, mas quando uso em uma rota, ao chamar ela é realizado o insert. Intrigante!?

Comment: O laravel cria um arquivo `laravel.log` em `storage/logs/`, verifique se tem algo lá.

Comment: no log informa que ela referencia uma coluna id de outra tabela, o estranho é que este dado exist. Vou analisar melhor aqui pra ver se existe mais inconsistencia

Comment: @AndréLins na verdade o erro estava ocorrendo devido ao item_id que não existia na outra tabela, porque achei que eu estivesse alterando o tipo de dado para passar como inteiro, mas na verdade o settype retorna 1 para TRUE e 0 para FALSE. Após corrigir funcionou normalmente. Obrigado pela força, sabes se você consegue fechar a minha pergunta ou como posso fechar?

Comment: Ótimo Mário, responde a pergunta e coloca essas resposta como a correta que acredito ser o suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a ajuda do @André_Lins nos comentarios o erro estava ocorrendo devido ao item_id que não existia na outra tabela, porque achei que estivesse alterando o tipo de dado para passar como inteiro, mas na verdade o **settype** retorna 1 para TRUE e 0 para FALSE. Após corrigir funcionou normalmente.